# Purescript Complex zero element (Purescipt by example exercies)

Tags: zero, purescript

I solve Purescript exercise from the book https://book.purescript.org/chapter6.html#multi-parameter-type-classes

I don't understand what "zero" statement is?

I have "Complex" type, and should define Semiring Complex instance of it.

```
newtype Complex
= Complex
 { real :: Number
 , imaginary :: Number
 }
```

Simple solution to define zero complex element (0.0+0.0i) as

```
instance semiringComplex :: Semiring Complex where
  zero = Complex {real: 0.0, imaginary: 0.0}
```

But another solution, presented in this book is

```
instance semiringComplex :: Semiring Complex where
 zero = Complex zero
```

I do not understand, how does this statement work ("Complex zero"), if zero defined as function (not as a Complex type element)

```
> :t zero
forall (a :: Type). Semiring a => a
```

And what I found tricky is

```
cz = Complex zero 
> cz
0.0+0.0i
```

How does PSCI understand that zero is 0.0+0.0i, but I did not define 0.0 constants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zero` is a method of the `Semiring` class. So it works for any type for which there is an instance of that class.

It just so happens that there is [an instance of the `Semiring` class for `Record r`](https://github.com/purescript/purescript-prelude/blob/f4cad0ae8106185c9ab407f43cf9abf05c256af4/src/Data/Semiring.purs#L83-L87) - that is, for records. As long as there are `Semiring` instances for all the record's field types. And the way that instance is defined is that `zero` is a record with all fields set to their respective `zero` values.

So, for example:

```hs
(zero :: { x :: Int, y :: Unit }) == { x: 0, y: unit }
```

Because `(zero :: Int) == 0` and `(zero :: Unit) == unit`

Or, in your particular case:

```hs
(zero :: { real :: Number, imaginary :: Number }) == { real: 0.0, imaginary: 0.0 }
```

Because `(zero :: Number) == 0.0`

Which means that writing `Complex zero` is equivalent to writing `Complex { real: 0.0, imaginary: 0.0 }`